# Import Contacts, Calendar Items that are "On My Computer" (or from an OLM file) into Exchange using Outlook 2011 Mac

Tags: macos, exchange, microsoft-outlook, mac

How do I import calendars and contacts from an OLM file (or that are "on my computer") into my Exchange account in Outlook 2011 for Mac? In Windows, usually this is handled by importing PST into your Exchange folder - it uses data files/archive folders and does not have the "on my computer" distinction.

Answer (score 0):

Install outlook then File -> Import -> OLM

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2413370